# Como funciona a tag allowBackup?

Tags: android, android-manifest

Gravo no dispositivo do usuário com `getSharedPreferences("config" ,Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` nome de login e algumas configurações do aplicativo.

Deixar a tag `allowBackup` como `true` implica em salvar somente estas informações?

Em que momento o backup/restore é executado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `allowBackup` determina se os dados da aplicação podem ser ou não guardados/restaurados pela infra-estrutura de backup e restauração.

Se o aplicativo correr num dispositivo Android 6 ou superior, nada é necessário fazer por parte do programador, o *backup/restore* é executado automaticamente.

O backup ocorre quando as seguintes circunstâncias se verificam:

- O dispositivo está inactivo.
- O dispositivo está a carregar.
- O dispositivo está conectado à rede WI-FI
- Passaram pelo menos 24 horas desde o último *backup*

O *restore* ocorre quando reinstala a aplicação.

Por padrão são guardadas todos os dados com excepção dos seguintes:

- Arquivos nas pastas retornadas pelos métodos `getCacheDir()` e `getCodeCacheDir()`.
- Arquivos existentes no *"external storage*", excepto aqueles na pasta retornada pelo método `getExternalFilesDir()`.
- Arquivos na pasta retornada pelo método `getNoBackupFilesDir()`

Nas versões anteriores ao Android 6 o *backup/restore* pode ser feito manualmente, via adb, usando a ferramenta [bmgr](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bmgr.html), ou recorrendo à [BackupApi](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/backupapi.html), estendendo a classe *BackupAgentHelper*.

Mais informação na documentação:

- [Configuring Auto Backup for Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html).
- [Using the Backup API](https://developer.android.com/training/backup/backupapi.html).
- [Data Backup](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).